# How do I capture this with sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to just capture the directory of this with sed and print just only the directory.

This is what I've got so far.

```
Name: 'srv', Host path: '/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart' (machine mapping), writable
```

I want just `'/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart'`

This is what I have got.

```
sed -n "s/'srv', Host path: \(.+\)/\1/p"
```

which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below,

```
$ echo "Name: 'srv', Host path: '/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart' (machine mapping), writable" | sed -n "s/.*'srv', Host path: \([^[:blank:]]\+\).*/\1/p"
'/Users/me/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart'
```